# Improve performance of the query that uses row_number

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables in `Postgres` - `testscores` and `questions`. `Testscores` is a table which stores information about the tests someone takes and also the questions that were involved in the corresponding tests. Both these tables have `questionid` which I'm joining them on.

Example datasets:

```
Testscores
TestscoreId    QuestionId    Created
100            224           2014-23-08
100            986           2014-12-12
100            126           2013-1-9
101            986           2015-2-7
101            376           2013-3-6
102            264           2015-30-11

Questions
QuestionId    irt_tlevel
986           easy
376           hard
264           medium
126           easy
986           medium
224           medium
```

I desire the following resultant:

```
TestscoreId    Questions    Created    Number    Irt_tlevel
100            3            2013-1-9   1         medium
100            3            2014-23-08 2         medium
100            3            2014-12-12 3         easy
101            2            2013-3-6   1         hard
101            2            2015-2-7   2         easy
102            1            2015-30-11 1         medium
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
    select a.testscoreid, count(a.*) as Questions, a.created, row_number() OVER(partition by a.created order by a.created) as Number, b.irt_tlevel
from asmt.testscores a join asmt.questions b
on a.questionid = b.questionid
where a.answered = true
group by a.testscoreid, a.created, b.irt_tlevel
order by Questions desc, a.created asc
```

I believe this query would give me the results I'm looking for but it takes forever to compute, it hasn't finished even once. `Testscores` has 88 Million+ rows and `Questions` has 164k rows.

Is there a better way to run this query? Can I get results faster? It has been an hour and I haven't got anything..
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here's exactly what I want:

`testscoreid` corresponds to a test taken by a testtaker. For every `testscoreid`, there are multiple `questionid` which correspond to the questions answered by the testtaker on a test. Considering all `testscoreid`, I would like to have a report that gives me the following data:

1. For all tests taken, Question #1 posted to the testtakers was `Easy` A times, `Medium` B times, `Hard` C times
2. For all tests taken, Question #2 posted to the testtakers was `Easy` X times, `Medium` Y times, `Hard` Z times

.

.

.

.

N. For all tests taken, Question #N posted to the testtakers was `Easy` P times, `Medium` Q times, `Hard` R times

`N` being the maximum number of questions attempted on the longest test, for example - if 5 people answered 200, 100, 400, 350 and 500 questions on 5 different tests, then `N` would be 500.

Comment: Can you share DDLs for your tables, or better yet, an sqlfiddle?

Comment: Alright, there are no indexes, no PK, no FK references. Looks like I'm stuck using what I have. I believe if I were to add an index on `testscoreid` and `questionid` with a FK reference to `Questionid`, my query would improve in performance.

Comment: Your query doesn't add up. You try to aggregate and not aggregate at the same time. Please start by telling us *what exactly* you intend to count and number ... And tell us which RDBMS and version you use.

Comment: I'm sorry the question wasn't super clear. I have added more details, hopefully that helps.